# No sound from build-in soundcard after upgrading to ubuntu 16.04

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, soundcard

It must be a software problem (potentially with the kernel). Since I have tried to run a live USB OS on the same machine, and it plays sounds well.

Second, it can detect the build-in soundcard.

```
$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC3220 Analog [ALC3220 Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

and it can be found by the lspci

```
$ lspci | grep -i audio
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation C610/X99 series chipset HD Audio Controller (rev 05)
03:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 0fbc (rev a1)

$ lspci -vv -s 00:1b.0
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation C610/X99 series chipset HD Audio Controller (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Dell C610/X99 series chipset HD Audio Controller
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 32
    Region 0: Memory at f7130000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

I also checked the pavucontrol and it outputs
[pavucontrol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4h1O.png)
and the sound control 
[sound](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K40HS.png)

I tried to reinstall the alsa, pulseaudio, the kernel and even update to another kernel, still without any luck.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Ubuntu 16.04 in my acer aspire e15 laptop. One person suggest me to upgrade to 18.04, and it worked!

Comment: I tried, but it failed with apt conflict check